# Display results from different API in Java console app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, console-application

I create a Spring Boot console app that gets a parameter from user via console and then read data from 3 different API. Then, I need to display data from all of these 3 API. At this moment, I am not sure if how should I call all of these APIs and then merge results.

Should I call all the APIs asynchronously? If so, how can I merge all the results into a Model? I think I should create a model that contains all the fields from 3 APIs. Is this approach seems good or what would you suggest?

On the other hand, should I create a Controller and Service then call the REST APIs from service (the parameter pass from console to Controller and then to Service)?

Comment: Does anybody else have never built Spring Boot console app?

Comment: At a high level, you can take an input from the CLI, then call your three APIs. Whether it's sync or async request doesn't really matter for the time being as all it changes is how you process it. You can then get the three results, create a model from it and return to the console. It's hard to help when the question is so open and opinion based,  so make a start and post any specific problems you run into.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need controller layer for this case. Just get parameters from user and send it to service that you created. Then call rest apis synchronously with RestTemplate or FeignClient(if always gonna be 3 api use resttemplate). And create model for per api that you called. And create a Model for your response. If all off your requests ends with success. Map theese 3 model to your response model and return this model from your service to wherever you want.